# Call to a member function row() error | $row = $query->row(); | CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, email

First let me say that I am primarily an iOS developer who is only recently exploring the thrilling adventures of full stack development.  I'm new to PHP and MySQL.  Having said that I have a problem which I hope requires a straight forward solution.

I am creating new api's for a client that has a preexisting database where they want to use an email address and password to authenticate users.

**My Code:**

Client:
I start out posting the email address and password from a form to the PHP script.  I have verified that the post is happening as expected, i.e. I am receiving the email address and password as entered by the user. (for my question, only the email is relevant.)  I don't want to get into an "encrypt your passwords" discussion.  That's not my question.

Server: (for what it's worth, this uses the CodeIgniter framework)

```
public function authenticateUser()
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    // for testing purposes, I'm just trying to echo the email address.
    echo $this->user_model->authenticateUser('user', $user, $password);
}
```

The authenticateUser function from the user_model:

```
 public function authenticateUser($table, $email, $password)
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = " . "$email";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $query->row();  // this is the line referenced in the error.

        return $row->email;
    }
```

For clarity, I am calling the parameter $user until it's passed to authenticateUser and then I'm calling it $email.  Obviously this is irrelevant.

Here is the error that's being generated:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in /path/to/core/MY_Model.php on line 76



 76 || $row = $query->row();
```

The email is stored in the database's email column in the user table as a varchar(100).

If I query using other criteria like a userId I can gain access to the email address just fine but I can't use the email address as search criteria for my query.  (sorry if I'm failing to use proper nomenclature.)

Is there something extra I have to do with an email address to use it as a way to authenticate a user?  Am I going about this all wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to consider my problem.

**Update**

I can't resolve my own question until 8 hrs after asked, but I wanted to update my question now so the community knows that it's resolved.  This fixed my problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = '".$email."'";
```

Thank you so much to everyone for the quick, cordial replies!  :)

Comment: where condition should be WHERE email = '" . $email."'";

Comment: @Rikesh. No. We can use row directly. Pls check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

change sql statement in model:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = '" . $email."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query in model function to:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM '".$table."" WHERE email = '".$email."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = '$email' ";
```

instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = " . "$email";
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is near to $email.ie not properly written.Rewrite your code

```
 public function authenticateUser($table, $email, $password)
    { 
       $sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = '".$email."'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $query->row();  // this is the line referenced in the error.

        return $row->email;
    }
```

You can use active records. That method easy to understand and no complicated structure.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Active record

```
$this->db->select('email');
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where('email',$email);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $result = $query->row();
    return $result->email;
}

return false;
```

Comment: I went with simply fixing the syntax because of time constraints.  However, I will try your solution during my next pass at code clean-up.  Thanks, Kanishka!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to everyone for the quick, cordial replies.

It seems I was formatting my query string improperly.

This fixed my problem:

$sql = "SELECT email FROM " . $table . " WHERE email = '".$email."'";

Again, much appreciated.  Have a great day!